# Printing a column to the console and having it display string values

Tags: r

Considering the following code:

```
cbind(data$Preceding.Phone, data$word, word.position)
```

I want to print `data$Preceding.Phone`, `data$word`, and `word.position` to the console because I just created a new column (`word.position`) and I want to see if it matches up with the other columns. The other columns contain string entries like "alabama" or "magazine". When I print this to the console they all come out as numbers. How can I print them as their string values?

Comment: `data[c("Preceding.Phone","word","position")]` and away you go.

Comment: @thelatemail wouldn't that try to return rows with those names? I must be missing something here

Comment: When you say "When I print this ...", what do you mean by "this"? Use `dput(head(data))` and copy the results into your question if you want to share you data (helps for making a reproducible example). Also, it would help to show the current, undesirable, output along with the definition of "this".

Comment: @rbatt - no, why would it? if `$` is being used, it is a `data.frame`, therefore selection by `data[c("string1","string2")]` returns columns not rows.

Comment: @thelatemail Right, it's late. I'm going to swing again: wouldn't that still return the "numbers"? I guess I just don't understand what the OP was asking, but apparently your answer worked out. But now I'm just curious!

Comment: @rbatt - `print.matrix` and `print.data.frame` presumably give different results due to matrix coercion of factor data to numeric values. I don't have R in front of me, but that would be my guess.